# PHP replace image content

Tags: php, regex

I'm not an expert with Regex, but I'm trying to convert an image URL to another and delete the height and width attributes...

```
$content = preg_replace('/src="([^"]*)(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp)"/', 'src="http://www.mysite.com/thumb.php?url=$1&width=500&height=500"', $post_content);

$content = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $content);

echo $content;
```

Echoing the results doesn't give me an image extension:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/thumb.php?url=http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image.&width=500&height=500" />
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `src\s*=\s*"([^"]+\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|bmp))"`

Answer (score 2):

The `$1` in your replacement-string refers to the *first capturing group* of your regex. In other words, the value of `$1` is the character sequence matched by the first `(...)` in the regex.

The problem is, your first set of parentheses does not include file extensions - hence the missing filename extension in the result.

Comment: @jlafforgue: I'm glad if I could help.